# Laravel 6 cannot run tests "PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner::getTest() must be of the type string"

Tags: phpunit, laravel-6

I'm trying to write very simple phpunit test

```
php artisan make:test CarTest

class CarTest extends TestCase
{
  /**
   * A basic feature test example.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function testExample()
  {
    $response = $this->get('/car');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
  }
}
```

Now I run it

```
phpunit ./tests/Feature/CarTest.php
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner::getTest() must be of the type string, array given, called in C:\Users\yasse\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php on line 125 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\lara6\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php:60
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php(125): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#1 C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php(101): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
#2 C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit(61): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#3 {main}
```

I installed phpunit globally and installed it locally (v8) using composer and run `composer dump-autoload` but issue is not resolved. How to fix this and be able to run this test?

Comment: Is there anything else in that stack trace?

Comment: Yes and post has been updated

Comment: Do not install PHPUnit globally. This is almost always a bad idea. And never ever mix a global installation of PHPUnit with a project-local one.

Comment: Any way to remove it globally?